# Can you make a Windows desktop app in Rust and winapi?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust, windows-rs

I've got a Windows application with a GUI written in Rust and winapi. Despite its GUI, it behaves like a console application. When the `exe` file is started, a `Command Prompt` window pops up, and the application is run from it. This is not what I want; a main window should open instead, as in all real desktop apps. How can I achieve this goal in Rust with winapi?

I've investigated some options. You can develop Windows desktop applications using [Tauri](https://tauri.app/) or [gtk-rs](https://gtk-rs.org/), but both of these techniques have drawbacks when used for Windows apps. More options may be found [here](https://medium.com/digitalfrontiers/gui-programming-with-rust-c71fe4051b1a). I've also tried the [windows-rs samples](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-samples-rs) available on the internet, but they're all console apps with a graphical user interface, which isn't what I'm looking for.

I also note that C++ desktop applications use the function `int APIENTRY wWinMain(...)` as the entry point while console applications use `int main(...)`, and `wWinMain` doesn't seem available in rust winapi.

Comment: There's probably a duplicate somewhere but I couldn't find it. You need to add the `#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]` attribute to your `main` function.

Comment: @Jmb `#!` designates an [inner attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html). It refers to the enclosing item (the module here), not a function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whether the system allocates a console for a newly created process is controlled by the `Subsystem` field in the Windows-specific [optional PE header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#optional-header-windows-specific-fields-image-only). The field is populated through the linker's [`/SUBSYSTEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem) command line option. The only relevant arguments for desktop applications are `CONSOLE` and `WINDOWS`. The former instructs the system to allocate a console on launch, whereas the latter won't.

You can instruct the linker to target the `WINDOWS` subsystem from Rust code by placing the per-module

```rust
#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]
```

attribute (see [windows-subsystem](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1665-windows-subsystem.html)) inside the main module of your application.

You'll find an example of this in the [core_app](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/blob/75a8260b65c81ae06444d16f9faab154bb517aae/crates/samples/core_app/src/main.rs#L1) sample of the `windows` crate.

This is the most convenient way to target the `WINDOWS` subsystem. You can also explicitly pass the linker flag along, e.g. by placing the following override into [*.cargo/config.toml*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html):

```ini
[build]
rustflags = [
    "-C", "link-arg=/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS",
]
```

This may or may not work, depending on the linker you happen to be using. Since the linker isn't part of the Rust toolchain, making sure that this works and has the intended effect is on you.

---

A note on the entry point's function name: It is irrelevant as far as the OS loader is concerned. It never even makes it into the final executable image anyway. The PE image only stores the (image-base-relative) [`AddressOfEntryPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#optional-header-standard-fields-image-only), and that symbol could have been named anything.

The concrete name is only relevant to the build tools involved in generating the respective linker input.

More info here: [WinMain is just the conventional name for the Win32 process entry point](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110525-00/?p=10573). The underlying principles apply to Rust just the same, particularly the aspect that the user-defined entry point (`fn main()`) isn't actually the executable's entry point.

Comment: Thank you for this knowledgeable answer. It not only solves the problem but also explains its basics. Incidentally, I could verify this solution on a couple of programs, including mine, but I didn't succeed with the core_app because I missed "a Windows developer license" or equivalent.